# Encapsular conjunto de tags HTML no VS Code ("ctrl + alt + enter" no Sublime Text)

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublime-text-3

Editando arquivos HTML no Sublime Text eu posso encapsular um conjunto de tags ou texto apenas selecionando o bloco e apertando <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> e digitando em seguida qual a tag que eu quero usar para encapsular o bloco. Gostaria de fazer o mesmo no Visual Studio Code mas até agora não faço a menor ideia.

Comment: Se você usa o Emmet dá pra selecionar o texto, pressionar `Ctrl + Shift + P` e digite `wrap`. Uma das opções é fazer o wrap com uma expressão do Emmet.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou, só que na verdade eu procurava um atalho de teclado mais prático.

Comment: Fiz essa mesma pesquisa há um tempo e, na época, não havia um atalho nativo. O que você pode fazer é adicionar o comando acima ao arquivo de atalhos.

Comment: @fernandosavio jovem, to usando a extensão que citei ai na resposta, tem sido bastante útil, as vezes te interessa.

Comment: Já positivei. Eu uso muito pouco essa _feature_ então vou deixar favoritado pra quando precisar. Valeu Hugo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isto definindo um atalho para a função `emmet wrap` do Visual Studio Code:

1. Vá em `Code` -> `Preferences` -> `Keyboard Shortcuts`.
2. Busque por `emmet wrap`.
3. Clique no sinal de mais `+` da opção `Emmet: Wrap with Abbreviation`.
4. Adicione o atalho que você deseja apertando <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, e depois <kbd>ENTER</kbd> para confirmar.
5. Agora basta selecionar um pedaço de código HTML e usar o atalho. Uma caixa de texto irá aparecer para você escrever a tag que deseja envolver o texto.

Answer (score 7):

Eu uso esse extensão **htmltagwrap** vc pode encontrar aqui: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradgashler.htmltagwrap

Essa extensão já vem com um atalho definido, basta selecionar o bolco de texto que quer encapsular e apartar <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> como vc pode ver no Gif abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Editando o atalho**

Se quiser mudar o atalho original para um que mais te agrade bastar ajustar aqui

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora pesquise e edite o novo atalho

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]